# What's the double semicolon (::) for in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm working with NetSuite's PHP toolkit and i get the error T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM from this line

```
$classname = get_class($object);
$typesmap = $classname::$paramtypesmap;  <---
```

I just want to know what's the '::' for, since is from there that i've seen the error is coming from.

All my dev work is on hold for this error and it has been almost a week.

My guess, it takes the value from $paramtypesmap to $typesmap depending the class name, which may seem kind of obvious, but the point is that i've never seen the '::' been used before.

Comment: You should try asking this in the stack overflow chat room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the scope resolution operator:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Example

```
<?php
class AClass {
    const THE_CONST_VALUE = 'The const value';
}

$classname = 'AClass';
echo $classname::THE_CONST_VALUE; // As of PHP 5.3.0

echo AClass::THE_CONST_VALUE;
?>
```